# Posting input text from form view to controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

So I have a form on my shared layout page that I want to simply post a text string to. I currently have a breakpoint sitting at the beginning of that action in the controller to test the form is working but it appears that it never gets there because it never hits the breakpoint. Here is my code anyone know what I am doing wrong?

View:

```
<form action="/RespondentSearch/Search" method="post" class="sidebarSearch">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="respondent search..." id="ac" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" /><span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
                    <input type="submit" value="" href="#moadalSearch" rel="lightbox" />
                </form>
```

Controller:

```
public class RespondentSearchController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Search(string search)
        {
            string stuff = search;

            return View();
        }
    }
```

My Visual Studio Debug Console though reads like there is an exception?

```
Following route: {controller}/{action}/{id} for request: http://localhost:56554/RespondentSearch/Search
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Following route: {controller}/{action}/{id} for request: http://localhost:56554/Home/Login
Following route: {controller}/{action}/{id} for request: http://localhost:56554/
```

My Developer Tools Browser Debug:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:56554/RespondentSearch/Search
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
search:asdf <--- This is what I was typing in
```

It appears it is getting there but I am not hitting my breakpoint still? I also added a temp view for it to just output something when its there and still nothing. It is like it is completely avoiding my controllers action.

Comment: Are you using a javascript library as well? I notice the submit button has an `href` attribute. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: Yes I believe it must be using one as well.

Comment: I just tested it in VS2012, mvc 4: it works.

Comment: Does the browser's debug console show a request being made?

Comment: @allencoded What you've posted should work, I asked about the javascript library because I suspect it may be intercepting the form submit event.

Comment: I just removed the href. The problem still seems to be there going to provide a dump of debug shortly

Comment: The network tab on the debug console will display any requests made along with the status code. If you do not see a request then it is possible javascript is doing `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` so that submission will not automatically happen.

Comment: If you bring up: http://localhost:56554/RespondentSearch/Search/5 in your browser does that work?

Comment: Nope I also did created a new action in the controller that doesn't require a HttpPost and then created a view on it. Then I navigated to it at  localhost:56554/RespondentSearch/Search it acts like it is going to go there then i just end up back on the localhost:56554 page. I inherited this project. I think some sort of odd redirection must be going on? Any other thoughts?

Comment: Figured it out the redirect came from an authentication error.